# What do you call the combination of endpoint and HTTP method in a REST API?

Tags: rest, api, api-design, web-api, http

Let's use the [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update) as an example. My understanding is that we refer to `/statuses/update` as an **endpoint** and we refer to `POST` as a HTTP **method**.

So what would term do you use to refer to the *pair* of these two things combined, i.e. `POST /statuses/update`?

1. "**Endpoint**". It seems most conventional to also refer to the combination as "endpoint". See for example: Stripe's documentation of some of its "endpoints" [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges?lang=curl) or [this overview page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/overview) for Twitter. The only problem is when I'm in a verbal conversation with someone saying "endpoint", it is sometimes ambiguous whether I mean just the end path `/statuses/update` or the combination `POST /statuses/update`.
2. "**Request method**" or "**API method**". For example, [Slack's REST API documentation](https://idratherbewriting.com/learnapidoc/docapis_resource_endpoints.html) refers to the end paths as "method URLs" and the collection of these as "API methods". Some API docs will list these pairs in the following manner:

   > **Available methods**
   >
   > POST /statuses/update
   >
   > GET /statuses/lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what would term do you use to refer to the pair of these two things combined, i.e. `POST /statuses/update`?

IMO that depends on the level of detail you want to describe:

- You could use ***REST API method*** for the general case. This makes it clear you'll need to have a REST endpoint in combination with an arbitrary HTTP command (in the end you can define your own, as long the server understands how to dispatch them, see [HTTP Methods](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/))
- You could classify the method further like

  - ***REST API read method*** (e.g. for `GET`)
  - ***REST API write method*** (e.g. for `POST`, `DELETE`, etc.)